# Obter o valor máximo de cada linha em um dataframe agrupado pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho um dataframe pandas com UF, Municipio, Classe_Acidente, Total.

Nesse dataframe cada Município aparece três vezes, uma para cada Classe de acidente (são 3 classes) e eu preciso obter o valor máximo para cada classe de acidente. Ou seja, tenho que percorrer o dataframe inteiro e obter o máximo de cada classe, por UF.

Fiz

```py
dfAcidentesPorMunicipiosPorUF = dfAcidentesPorMunicipiosPorUF.groupby(['uf','municipio','classificacao_acidente'])['classificacao_acidente'].count().reset_index(name="Total")
```

E retornou agrupado corretamente, mas, não consigo obter o máximo.

```py
    uf  municipio     classificacao_acidente       Total
0   AC  ACRELANDIA    Com Vítimas Feridas           10
1   AC  ASSIS BRASIL  Sem Vítimas                   6
2   AC  BRASILEIA     Com Vítimas Fatais            5
3   AC  BRASILEIA     Com Vítimas Feridas           8
4   AC  BRASILEIA     Sem Vítimas                   2
5   AC  BUJARI        Com Vítimas Fatais            5
6   AC  BUJARI        Com Vítimas Feridas           65
7   AC  BUJARI        Sem Vítimas                   26
47  TO  PARAISO DO    Sem Vítimas                   59
47  TO  PEDRO AFONSO  Com Vítimas Feridas           4
47  TO  PEIXE         Com Vítimas Fatais            18
47  TO  PEIXE         Com Vítimas Feridas           23
47  TO  PIRAQUE       Com Vítimas Feridas           5
47  TO  PIRAQUE       Sem Vítimas                   1
47  TO  KENNEDY       Com Vítimas Fatais            6
47  TO  KENNEDY       Com Vítimas Feridas           25
47  TO  KENNEDY       Sem Vítimas                   22
```

Alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Já quebrei a cabeça, mas, não consegui.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com `groupby` e `transform` é possível selecionar o valor mais alto de cada classe por estado

```
df = dfAcidentesPorMunicipiosPorUF.copy()
df.loc[df['Total'] == df.groupby(['uf','classificacao_acidente'])['Total'].transform('max')]

saida:
    uf  municipio   classificacao_acidente  Total
2   AC  BRASILEIA   Com Vítimas Fatais      5
5   AC  BUJARI      Com Vítimas Fatais      5
6   AC  BUJARI      Com Vítimas Feridas     65
7   AC  BUJARI      Sem Vítimas             26
8   TO  PARAISO DO  Sem Vítimas             59
10  TO  PEIXE       Com Vítimas Fatais      18
15  TO  KENNEDY     Com Vítimas Feridas     25
```

Comment: Mano do céu, rodou certinho. Vou ler a documentação desse transform. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você afirmou querer agrupar por estados e por classificação de acidente, então eu não vejo a necessidade de você incluir o município no código.
Verifique se a linha abaixo resolve seu problema:

```py
dfAcidentesPorMunicipiosPorUF = 
dfAcidentesPorMunicipiosPorUF.groupby(['uf','classificacao_acidente']) 
['classificacao_acidente'].count().reset_index(name="Total")
```

Você também pode tentar com a função `max()` ao invés de `count()`.

Comment: Cláudio, obrigado. Já  tentei sem o UF e  com o .max(). Acontece que sempre retorna todos os municípios e não apenas um município por estado. Eu até poderia usar os municípios sem o UF, embora eu precise do resultado com o UF,município,classificacao_acidente. Obrigado.